# Use client certificate in WCF service net tcp

Tags: wcf, certificate

I have a WCF application running as net tcp and installed a server certificate (xxx.domain.com) in server.

Enabled Transport with certificate security. IIS web site configured and its working fine with above certificate also its not installed in local machine as its found correct root ca and intermediate certificate .

Can i call the wcf service with out installing certificate if yes which one i should use Root CA or intermediate .
Please see the certificate chain below

**Root CA**
   **Intermediate**
   **xxx.domain.com**

Here is the code used in client

```
channel.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
StoreName.CertificateAuthority,
X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
"tried intermediate and root CA its not working ");
```

Answer (score 0):

When a WCF service created by `Nettcpbinding` authenticates the client with a certificate, we need to specify a service certificate in the service credentials.

```
sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "5ba5022f527e32ac02548fc5afc558de1d314cb6");
```

Then the service will work properly. Subsequently, the client should provide a client certificate when calling the service since the `Clientcredentialtype` property is `Certificate` on the server-side.

```
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

Client-side.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "f0969c5725b2f142b7f150515ec2bd12bc45250b");
            var result = client.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

During this process, please note we should install the certificate each other in the Root CA so that the certificate trust relationship between the client-side and the server-side can be established.
Look back to your question, the cause might be the certificate trust relationship cannot be established between the client-side and the server-side. We have to ensure that the client-side has installed the service certificate in the Root CA and the server has installed the client certificate in the Root CA.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: So we need to install the certificate in client machine . I have one web site using the same certificate and its loading https in client machine with out installing certificate . can we use same concept in nettcp

Comment: I didn't fully get your point.  Do you mean that whether we are able to call the service on the client machine without installing a service certificate?  As long as the certificate is trusted by the client machine, there is no need to complete this action. Most of the certificate issued by the authoritative third-party organization is trusted by the client machine, such as Go Daddy, GlobalSign. As a result, the browser has a secure lock mark when accessing the website secured by the certificate issued by those organizations.

Comment: Alternatively, the server-side changes the `clientcredentialtype` to None, this also works without installing the service certificate.